# Creating an elevation profile along a KML road based on ASC files

Tags: kml, elevation, ascii, profile

I want to make the elevation profile of a road in KML. I've found this [online tool](http://www.geocontext.org/publ/2010/04/profiler/) but its does not gives accurate elevations. I already have `.asc` files of the whole area that includes the KML route with accurate elevation details. Is there a way to extract the corresponding route elevation profile from the `.asc` files? Which tool can I use to do it?

Comment: Do you have access to gis software? Perhaps QGIS is a free gis software that you can use to do what you ask

Comment: I have acces to ArcGis suit (ArcMap, MapInfo, etc.. ) is it suitable for the task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for ArcGis (you will need the 3D analyst extension).

1) Load the .asc file in ArcMap.

2) In the Arctoolbox - > Conversion Tool > From KML to Layer (to transform the KML in a file suitable for ArcGis). The new file automatically loads in ArcMap

3) Right click on your converted road and select "Convert feature to graphics"

4) Select the created graphic with the select elements tool (the black arrow)

5) in the 3d analyst toolbar click on "Profile Graph"

Comment: Thank you, That's the hint. Now I just need to find a way to align the polygon layer withe the asc layer.